# Does this guarantee access the first element of the map?

Tags: java, hashmap

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>;

...

Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = sortByValue(map);
Integer max = sortedMap.keySet().iterator().next();
```

What I need is to fetch the first element in the map, which is the max element after sorted.

Edited: The sorted map looks like:

```
John->100
   Mary->50
   Mike-> 2
   ...
```

Comment: what magic `sortByValue()`  does ?

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Cannot you just `Sets.newTreeSet(sortedMap.values()).iterator().next()` ?
We know nothing about `sortedMap` capabilities, as it could be a different map than the input.

Comment: sortByValue returns a new map, whose elements are sorted by the values, i.e. integers.

Comment: If it is a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), no. "This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."

Comment: If the sorted order can't guarantee the order of the map, what's the point of sorting the map?

Comment: If you want to sort a map by value, I believe a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) can be used with a custom comparator (because it defaults to sorting by keys).

Comment: I already sorted using my sortByValue method I wrote. My question is now, whether the first element is the max integer because it's sorted in decreasing order.

Comment: If your sorting method returns a `HashMap`, then there is no guarantee that it will be the first element. You can look into storing the sorted map as a [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) as well as it preserves the insertion order.

Comment: You want to get 100 from the map, right ?

Comment: @don, yes, 100.

Comment: "If the sorted order can't guarantee the order of the map, what's the point of sorting the map?" If it's a HashMap, then there is indeed no point in it. In fact, "I sorted this map" is not a meaningful statement to make in the first place. There are things you can do to a HashMap; sorting is not one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are some `Map` implementations that have a notion of order, this is not part of the Map contract. In particular `HashMap` does not guarantee any ordering of the entries.

It depends what you did here in `sortByValue` and if the map that is returned preseves some order.

Comment: My sorted map actually returns a LinkedHashMap. Sorry for the confusion.